# Perforce reconcile command doesn't recognize files opened for edit that were deleted

Tags: perforce

Scenario:

I have a folder of files that are generated by an external tool that we check into Perforce for revision control, however we don't have knowledge ahead of time about when it's going to add/remove files from that structure.

So today our workflow is to checkout the entire directory, and then allow the tool to regenerate all of the files/hierarchy.  When I run the reconcile command it successfully finds new files, but it fails to find files that were deleted.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade your Perforce server to 2014.2:

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/user/relnotes.txt

```
Minor new functionality in 2014.2

    #841159 **
        'p4 reconcile' will now detect files that are open for edit but
        missing from the client, and reopen them for delete.
```

A workaround is to do "p4 revert -k" prior to "p4 reconcile" so that it'll start over from scratch.  The "-k" option tells revert to forget the files are open but NOT to actually undo the local changes.

A modified workflow that might make more sense if you're already using "p4 reconcile" religiously is to skip the "p4 edit" and use either the "allwrite" client spec option or the "+w" filetype modifier to make the files writable.

Comment: Thanks Sam.  Confirmed that our server is still running 2013.2, and I have almost zero pull for IT to upgrade it :(  I'm thinking that using chmod to add the necessary write permissions is the way to go here. Thanks